# .rdata and .csv saving errors for shiny datatable radio-button inputs

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I am relatively new to ShinyR apps and would like some help! I am trying to save input from a radiobutton table adapted from [here](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-radio/)) as .rdata file and .csv file once the `actionButton` has been clicked. Ideally, I would like to the results within a matrix/dataframe with each response in a column, and the username as row name.

I would like it to look like this: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO0sW.png)

I tried it with a smaller reproducible version below and get **two different errors**, depending on how the table has been filled out. The first error occurs if I *fill out all responses* where my .csv file are scrambled letters like this:

[saved_csv_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MX5k2.png)

I cannot figure out why it is saved like this in the .csv file as it looks perfectly fine in the .RData file. However, with my .RData file, the rbind does not work properly, as it overwrites the previous results every time I enter new responses it. So my two questions are 
**1) Why is the data in .csv file is saved in unreadable letters?

2) How do I correctly`rbind` in the shinyR app?**

Any help would be really appreciated many thanks!

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

Agree_Likert <- c("Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Neither", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "NA")

qu_page <- c("Dogs are more friendly than cats",
             "I like to gte things done",
             "I am a cat person",
             "I make my bed ever morning",
             "I am more creative in a messy environement",
             "I would describe myself as friendly",
             "I enjoy getting out of my comfort zone")

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    h2("Questions"),
    p("Below are a number of statements, please indicate your level of agreement"),
    DT::dataTableOutput('question_matrix'),
    verbatimTextOutput('list'),
    textInput(inputId = "username", label= "Please enter your username"),
    actionButton(inputId= "submit", label= "submit")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    m = matrix(
      as.character(1:length(Agree_Likert)), nrow = length(qu_page), ncol = length(Agree_Likert), byrow = TRUE,
      dimnames = list(qu_page, Agree_Likert)
    )
    for (i in seq_len(nrow(m))) {
      m[i, ] = sprintf(
        '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>',
        qu_page[i], m[i, ]
      )
    }
    m
    output$question_matrix = DT::renderDataTable(
      m, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', server = FALSE,
      options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE),
      callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
                    var $this = $(this.node());
                    $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
                    $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');
  });
                    Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
                    Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
    )

    ## print lists in App
    #test_list<<-NULL
    # output$list = renderPrint({
       #test_list[i] <<- str(sapply(qu_page, function(i) input[[i]]))
       #test_list

   #})

    observeEvent(
      input$submit,{
        # if it exists should inclue a matrix called responses
        if (file.exists("responses.Rdata")) 
          load(file="responses.Rdata")
        if (!file.exists("responses.Rdata")){
          responses<<- matrix(ncol= length(qu_page), nrow=0)
          colnames(responses) <<- qu_page
        } 
        # unlist values from json table
        listed_responses <<- sapply(qu_page, function(i) input[[i]])

        # create one row matrix with unlisted responses
        unlisted_responses <<- t(as.matrix(unlist(listed_responses)))

        # add username as input row
        rownames(unlisted_responses) <<- input$username

        # combine it with preexiating df responses
        responses <<- rbind(responses, unlisted_responses)


        save(responses, file = "responses.Rdata")
        save(responses, file = "responses.csv")
        }
      )
    }
)
```

Comment: Didn't get through your code, but the last line hit me: if you want to write a `csv` file, you should use `write.csv` (and `read.csv` to read it).

Comment: Thank you! That makes the .csv file readable! I changed it to, to append data rows: `write.table(responses,sep = ",", file = "responses.csv", append= TRUE, quote= FALSE)`

However, now whenever I update the csv file by adding a row, it just copy-pastes the exact same data that was first entered into the file. Do you know what the reason could be?